# Stop application from crashing in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

Behavior of `Express.js` regarding to uncaught exceptions has been fairly random to me. Sometimes, the request returns with code `500` internal error and continue running, sometimes it crashes `[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`. When does the later happen? Can I stop it from crashing by returning all errored requests with code `500`?

Answer (score 0):

Those errors belong to two separate categories.

First error `500 internal error` belongs to operational error category. This type of error occurs due to external circumstances like socket hang-up or request timeout. Application throws an error, but it is handled later during execution. Server responds with error 500 status code instead of usual 200. After sending response it continues to work.

Second error `[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...` belongs to programmer error category. It happens when an unhandled error occurs which is caused by programmer error thus making it a bug. It might be because your code cannot be parsed by javascript parser thus making it a syntax error. In some cases it might also happen due to a semantic error ie. Reference Error about missing module or undefined variable.

After such an error server stops working and will be started by nodemon when  the change in code is detected.

Such errors should be left unhandled, because trying to handle them might cause unpredictable consequences in the program running.

I recommend you a great article about error handling in node.js https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors

Comment: This is not entire true. I see the app crash with a semantic error such as `Uncaught ReferenceError`. It happens during a third party library callback and it crashes the app.

Comment: Short of reading the linked article, let me get this right. Are you actually saying that if the app crashes in production, you're meant to go change some files on the server for it to start up again!?